# You haven't finished reading the books

Tags: grammar

My son and I were in the car.

He wanted to go to the library to return the books.

> "You haven't finished reading the books."
>
> "You haven't finished reading these books."

I told him.

The books were at home.

As the context above, I should use "the" or "these"?

Comment: If the books were at home, 'those' could be used IMO.

Comment: "the books" could also be used to refer to the books in question, that is, to the ones parent and child knew were in the process of being read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be either

"the books [you are talking about]"

or

"those books [that you left at home],"

but it would not be "these books" unless you mean

"these books [that you're talking about],"

which I don't think is what you mean.